# How to use selection on many2one field

Tags: odoo

As described [here](https://doc.openerp.com/6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/field_type/#relational-types), I have created a `many2one` field with custom selection function:

```
def _get_partner_sup(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    obj = self.pool.get('res.partner')
    ids = obj.search(cr, uid, [('supplier','=',True), ('is_company','=',True)])
    res = obj.read(cr, uid, ids, ['name', 'id','email'], context)
    res = [(r['id'], r['name']) for r in res]     
    return res

_columns = {
    'partner_sup_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Select Supplier 2 ', selection=_get_partner_sup),
}
```

But it's still like a normal `many2one` field.

Answer (score 2):

Skip using function _get_partner_sup, just in XML use both

```
widget="selection"
```

and

```
domain=[('supplier','=',True),('is_company','=',True)]
```

Answer (score 0):

On the XML view, maybe you need to put 'widget="selection"' when you define this field.

Comment: I want _columns = {
    'partner_sup_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Select Supplier 2 ', selection=_get_partner_sup),
} because of result from function